# Recursive Logic for Linked List in Java

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to find a way to write a java program with recursion logic for insertion, searching as well as traversal for singly linked list. But, I don't know how I can do it while my head node is private. Here is the piece of code I have written :

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
}
public class SingleList {
    private Node head;

    public SingleList() {
        head = null;
    }
    void insert(Node temp, int num, int n) {
        //Suggest some code here
    }

    boolean search(Node temp, int num) {
        //Suggest some code here
    }
    void traverse(Node temp) {
        //Suggest some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: The node is private, but the methods are part of the class, so they have access to its private members. So what's the problem?

Comment: How can I pass the head as argument for the first time entry into the function? I will need that argument for further recursions.

Comment: Well, let's take the example of insert(). You want to insert the value num at the position n. So there should be a public method insert(int num, int n). And this method should call recursively another, private method insert(Node node, int num, int n). The first call would pass `this.head`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any problem to access the head from your class.

In addition, the `Node` class is probably irrelevant for any other class other than `SingleList` class, it will be a better idea to include it within the `SingleList` class

```
public class SingleList {

    private class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
    }

    // Rest of your class code...

}
```